# Wordpress: Sort usermeta data when using get_user_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have defined `$table_name_employee` as a table in my plugin that has a bunch of user info in it. The `ID` field mirrors the field in `wp_users`

That being said, I have this code...

```
$SQLQuery="select * from {$table_name_employee}";
$wpdb->query($SQLQuery);
$results=$wpdb->get_results($SQLQuery,ARRAY_A);

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $result['ID'] );
    $last_name = $all_meta_for_user['last_name'][0];
    $first_name = $all_meta_for_user['first_name'][0];
    $doc_training_responsibility_option.= "\t<option value='{$result['ID']}'>{$last_name}, {$first_name}</option>\n";
}
```

Later in my code I use `$doc_training_responsibility_option` to output the `<option>` inside the `<select>`.

It works as expected; however, the results are not sorted. I have tried several ways to add the data into an array instead of defining `$doc_training_responsibility_option` immediately. My intent was to sort the array by last name and then output that array to `$doc_training_responsibility_option` but I have failed on each attempt.

**** UPDATE ****

My attempt is below...

```
$SQLQuery="select * from {$table_name_employee}";
$wpdb->query($SQLQuery);
$results=$wpdb->get_results($SQLQuery,ARRAY_A);

$r=array(); $i=0;
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $result['ID'] );
    $r[$i]['ID']=$result['ID'];
    $r[$i]['last_name']=$all_meta_for_user['last_name'][0];
    $r[$i]['first_name']=$all_meta_for_user['first_name'][0];
    $i++;
}

// ************************************************
// NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE TO SORT $r BY last_name
// ************************************************

foreach ($r as $result)
{
    $doc_training_responsibility_option.= "\t<option value='{$result['ID']}'>{$result['last_name']}, {$result['first_name']}</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you try `ORDER BY` in your query?

Comment: @Mauro - Can't use `ORDER BY` because `last_name` is not in `$table_name_employee` - It is in `wp_usermeta` - That is why I use `get_user_meta()` after getting the results from the query.

Comment: Then, use [WP User query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Answer (score 1):

right now you are getting the user ID in this varible:

```
$result['ID']
```

Now you need to get all users from `wp_usermeta` and order by last name.

So you need to use [get users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to accomplish your task.

```
$u = get_users(array('blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'], 'meta_key' => 'last_name', 'orderby' => 'meta_value'));

foreach ($u as $user) {
            $n = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_name', true );
            echo "<option>";
            echo $n;
            echo "</option>";
        }
```

Comment: I tweaked your code and got it working. See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mauro comment, I created the code below which worked.

```
// Create list of plugin users
$SQLQuery="select ID from {$table_name_employee}";
$wpdb->query($SQLQuery);
$results=$wpdb->get_results($SQLQuery,ARRAY_A);

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $plugin_user[]=$result[ID];
}


// Get list of WP users (sorted)
$u = get_users(array('blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'], 'meta_key' => 'last_name', 'orderby' => 'meta_value'));

foreach ($u as $user)
{
    // See if WP user is also a plugin user
    if(in_array($user->ID,$plugin_user) )
    {
        $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
        $last_name=$all_meta_for_user['last_name'][0];
        $first_name=$all_meta_for_user['first_name'][0];

        $doc_training_responsibility_option.= "\t<option value='{$user->ID}'>{$last_name}, {$first_name}</option>\n";
    }
}
```